# My Nested IF Function is failing, but why?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have done a lot of research on this but i am struggling to find the answer due to each question being specific to their data.

I have a nested IF function, where i would like it to change the cell value to either "Completed" or "Not Completed" depending on a few criteria.

Firstly, the function looks through the Data and then sees if the cell value matches a value in the data, then if true, looks at the next value and if there is a match, it then goes through the corresponding matches and sees if all values are set to delivered. If they are all delivered, the cell should change to "Completed", and if not "Not Completed".

Below is the function i have, that currently fails on the first IF.

```
{=IF('Sub Tasks'!J:J=A2,IF('Sub Tasks'!K:K=B2,IF('Sub Tasks'!AA:AA="Delivered","Completed","Not Completed"),"NOT TRUE1"),"NOT TRUE2")}
```

There are also screenshots of the test i am running.

OutputSheet
[image]
OriginalData
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Sub Tasks'!J:J,A2,'Sub Tasks'!K:K,B2,'Sub Tasks'!AA:AA,"Delivered")=COUNTIFS('Sub Tasks'!J:J,A2,'Sub Tasks'!K:K,B2),"Completed","Not Completed")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried it and it doesn't seem to be working. Does the forumla not need to be array? Also, why is CountIf better than nested IF?

Comment: Your nested if will not work as it use implicit references.  with the formula in row two it will only return the values from row 2.  As to my formula, what is not working?  My assumption is that for it to be marked as complete all the T_number and Milestone grouping must be "Delivered" if any one is not then it is marked as Not complete.

Comment: Sorry i was being stupid!!! It did work! Thank you. Out of curiosity, why CountIFS and why does it not have to be an array

Comment: COUNTIFS is not an array type formula and does not need to be array entered, it was made to count patterns. we are just comparing the two to ensure all are marked "Delivered".